# Send sticker (using file_id, not url) with Telegram and BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram

Unable to send sticker using "file_id". Documentation on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) comes only with sample using "url"

Trying to send like this:

```
activity.ChannelData = new { method = "sendSticker", parameters = new { sticker = new { file_id = "CAADAgADmwEAAoo0zQirH-KhlK1ZMwI", width = 512, height = 355 } } };
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(activity);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: As you said, "Documentation on learn.microsoft.com comes only with sample using "url"": that may be because `file_id` is not supported

Comment: Is there some reservation about using URL?  What is the use case here?

Comment: Yes. But as described on Telegram Bot API documentations it is preffered way to use file_id.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for an answer to this question, but in the end I figured it out myself. Sorry for the 4 year late reply) C#:

```
private static async void OnMessageHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    var msg = e.Message;
    var sticker_to_send = await client.SendStickerAsync(chatId: int_chat_id, sticker: msg.Sticker.FileId);
}
```

P.S.
I just signed up here just for this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue using Telegram.Bot api with NET 8 and C# and came across with the right way:

```
Message sendSticker = await botClient.SendStickerAsync(
chatId: chatId,
sticker: InputFile.FromFileId("CAADAgADmwEAAoo0zQirH-KhlK1ZMwI"),
cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

More in the [quickstart guide](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/2/send-msg/photo-sticker-msg.html) from github. Cheers.